# Firestore transaction fails with "Transaction failed all retries"

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm running a very simple Firestore transaction which checks for the presence of a document, before writing to it if absent.

(The use case is registering a username - if it's not already registered, the current user gets to grab it)

Here's a snippet of the relevant Flutter code:

```dart
DocumentReference usernameDocRef =
    Firestore.instance.collection(_USERNAMES).document(username);

await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  var snapshot = await transaction.get(usernameDocRef);
  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    transaction.set(usernameDocRef, {
      _UsernamesKey.userid: _user.id,
    });
  }
});
```

This is failing with an exception "Transaction failed all retries".

Based on the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transaction_failure), failure can occur for two reasons:

> - The transaction contains read operations after write operations. Read operations must always come before any write operations.
> - The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again. The transaction is retried a finite number of times.

I don't think I trigger either of those. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've raised an issue about this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18747

Comment: Finally you could get to solve the issue?

Comment: A transaction can also fail due to rules (authentication) issues in which case you should get a `403` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has recently been fixed - https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1206.

If you are using the [master channel](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels), the fix should be available already. For the other channels (dev, beta, stable) YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

The [example transaction in the documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore) uses `await` on its call to `update`.  Perhaps you need the same on your call to `set`:

```
await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  var snapshot = await transaction.get(usernameDocRef);
  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    await transaction.set(usernameDocRef, {
      _UsernamesKey.userid: _user.id,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I get the same error with this modification too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try using the reference from the **fresh snapshot** and **not** from the **original document reference**. If this doesn't work, try changing [set] to [update] as I remember having the same error as you have experience now.

```
DocumentReference usernameDocRef =
        Firestore.instance.collection(_USERNAMES).document(username);

await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  var snapshot = await transaction.get(usernameDocRef);
  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    await transaction.update(snapshot.reference, {
      _UsernamesKey.userid: _user.id,
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Flutter/Dart expert, but I expect you have to return something from within the transaction, so that Firestore knows when you're done:

```
await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  var snapshot = await transaction.get(usernameDocRef);
  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    return transaction.set(usernameDocRef, {
      _UsernamesKey.userid: _user.id,
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: I still get the same error using this approach too :-(

Comment: Sorry it didn't help Duncan. In that case I have no idea what's going wrong. Hopefully somebody else sees is.